# css not working in child theme when using ng-include

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I'm using AdminLTE template to create a simple web app. I'm traing to use AngularJS for my front end. I want to split my theme in some child themes because it's easier to mantein. To do this, i use "ng-include" directive, but the html in the child view isn't beeing display correctly:

[image: Without ng-include directive]

[image: With ng-include directive]

in the past when I was using php with  i don't have the same problem. WHat can I do?

Comment: I suppose, from `theme` you mean `templates` . can u share a demo. From what I have worked, `ng-include` works well with css. Can you check the scope of parent `class` once

Answer (score 0):

Solution. I was using:

when using tag "ng-Include" the css don't work. So i include the first line of profile.html and i add the ng-Include directive:

This work fine for me!